# 60 tilted circles with a hole in the center

Tags: python, geometry, shapes, spiral

I have made something where there are 60 circles to form one huge one, but I'd like to know how you can create a small hole in the middle. Thanks for helping!

[What mine looks like rn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJD9X.png)
[What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEPmz.png)

*my code*

```
import turtle

turtle.setup(1000,1000)
turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.speed(0)
turtle.up()
turtle.goto(0,0)
turtle.down()
n = 60
for i in range(n):
    turtle.circle(200)
    turtle.left(360/n)
```

Comment: Move a little forward before drawing the circle, don't forget to move back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, and tinker with the values.

```
import turtle

turtle.setup(1000,1000)
turtle.hideturtle()

turtle.speed(0)
turtle.up()
turtle.goto(0,0)
turtle.down()
n = 20
for i in range(n):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.backward(150)
    turtle.right(15)
    turtle.down()

    turtle.circle(100)

    turtle.up()
    turtle.left(15)
    turtle.forward(150)
    turtle.up()

    turtle.left(360/n)
```